# Are the 1 dimensional loop spaces in homotopy type theory commutative?

Tags: foundations, type-theory

Theorem 2.1.6 of the Homotopy Type Theory book proves that $\Omega^{2}A$ is always commutative, using a similar argument to the one used for loop spaces in algebraic topology.

Isn't it also the case (left unstated) that one can just use simple path induction to show that this is the case for $\Omega A$ as well? Since $\Omega A :\equiv a =_{A} a$, can't we just show that $p \cdot q = q \cdot p$ by assuming that both $p$ and $q$ are $\mathrm{refl}_{a}$ and using path induction?  Doesn't this, much simpler, proof extend to $\Omega^{n}A$ for any $n$?  What am I missing?

Comment: Well, the first loop space is in fact not commutative in general, so...

Comment: This is loop space of a type, not of a topological space.

Comment: Yes, and the loop space of a type isn't commutative in general either. Homotopy type theory has semantics which include, say, the case of groupoids, and the loop space of a groupoid can be any group.

Comment: Ok, I believe you, but please explain the flaw in my argument.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about homotopy type theory to turn "assuming that both $p$ and $q$ are $\text{refl}_a$ and using path induction" into an argument I understand. Can you add more details?

Comment: According to section 2 of the HoTT Book (page 80 in my version):

Informally, the induction principle for identity types says that if we want to construct an object (or prove a statement) which depends on an inhabitant $p : x =_{A} y$ of an identity type, then it suffices to perform the construction (or the proof) in the special case when $x$ and $y$ are the same (judgmentally) and p is the reflexivity element $refl_{x} : x = x$ (judgmentally).

Comment: Now using the above, to show that for $p, q : a =_{A} a$ we have $p \cdot q = q \cdot p$, we can replace both (or just one if we rather) of $p$ or $q$ by $refl_{a}$.  So we just need to show that $refl_{a} \cdot refl_{a} = refl_{a} \cdot refl_{a}$, which is true judgementally, so we are done. 

I tried putting this proof through the Lean proof assistant, and the proof checked just fine.  There is almost assuredly an error in my proof, but it is in the spirit of all of the other proofs from section 2.1 of the HoTT book, and seems to pass a (admittedly new) proof checker, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured this out.  You cannot apply path induction when there are two fixed endpoints.  Indeed if you try to actually use the inductor of identity types to create some inhabitant of type $\Pi_{a:A}\Pi_{p,q:a=a} p\cdot q = q \cdot p$ you will fail at the first step of trying to find the correct type family $D : \Pi_{x,y : A} (x =_{A} y) \rightarrow U$ to express your goal.  The HoTT book mentions this in 1.12.1.

The reason Lean accepts the proof is because in the non-HoTT version of lean, the *only* inhabitant of $a=a$ is $\mathrm{refl}_a$.